In my Android device google lens only three options(translate,search and homework)are available
In my Android device google lens only three options(translate,search and homework)are available at the bottom. Also the search results are not working. Whats the problem and how can i fix it.
havoc os 2.5 with pico gapps android 9
i  want to get all the bottom options like translate,homework,shopping that are available on other android devices
